# how to index data using index_create() in elastic package in R

Tags: r, elasticsearch, ropensci

This is my code in R to index iris data.

```
library(elastic)
iris<-datasets::iris

body <- list(data = list(iris))

index_create(index = 'iris',body = body)
```

but it gives the following error.

```
Error: 400 - Failed to parse content to map. 
Please explain how to give data in the body of the index_create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elastic` maintainer here. `index_create` is only for creating an index as the function name indicates. That is, create an index, not create an index and insert data into the index. From your example you probably want

```
index_create(index = "iris")
docs_bulk(iris, "iris")
```

Comment: index_create("index")
mapping_create(index = "indexname", type = "data", body = map.body)
docs_bulk(dataset, index = "indexname", type = "data").it give me error saying that 400 error. index already exists.Execution halted. but if i use elastic() function of elasticsearchr package. it indexed data successfully but with  data mapping issues.

Comment: I think error is clear and is the correct one. You can't create an index that already exists

Comment: elastic("http://localhost:9200", "customdata24","customdata24") %create% mapping_custom(toJSON(map.body,auto_unbox = TRUE))
invisible(docs_bulk(index = "customdata24", type = "customdata24",myData,raw = FALSE, chunk_size = 100000))..........Done by using mapping_custom() function of elastic package by passing custom json arguments.